# 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE when using SpringBoot HttpRequestTest with multipart/form-data

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, multipartform-data

I have the following endpoint:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
public ResponseEntity<LocalizedStatusMessage> postFormFileUpload(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id, @RequestBody Map<String, JsonNode> rawFormValues, @RequestParam("attachments") MultipartFile[] attachments) {...}
```

The endpoint should send a json as well as any number of attachments

which I would like to test using the following test, using `@SpringBootTest` HttpRequestTest:

```java
@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

public void givenMultipartFormData_whenEndpointIsCalled_thenReturn201() {
    String id = "fileTest" //irrelevant
    String content = "{\"fileTestField}\": []}" //irrelevant
    MultipartFile[] attachments = new MultipartFile[]{};
    
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    body.add("id", id);
    body.add("content", content);
    for (MultipartFile attachment : attachments) {
        body.add("attachments", attachment.getResource());
    }

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

    String url = domain + port + formPath + "/" + id;

    ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestEntity, String.class);
    // THEN return 201 CREATED
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, result.getStatusCode());
}
```

Instead of getting a `201 CREATED`, I receive a `415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE`.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can try by following example, while adjusting to your requirement:

```
@RequestMapping(path = {"MYURL"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    Single<List<MyResponse>> myMethod(
            @RequestPart("metadata") myRequest metadata,
            @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        return // TODO
    }
    
    
    private boolean upload() {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
            MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

            MultiValueMap<String, String> fileMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            ContentDisposition fileContentDisposition = ContentDisposition
                .builder("form-data")
                .name("file")
                .filename("testfile.txt")
                .build();
            fileMap.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, fileContentDisposition.toString());
            HttpEntity<byte[]> fileEntity = new HttpEntity<>(((ByteArrayResource) testFileContent).getByteArray(), fileMap);
            body.add("file", fileEntity);

            MultiValueMap<String, String> metadataMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            ContentDisposition metadataContentDisposition = ContentDisposition
                .builder("form-data")
                .name("metadata")
                .filename("testmetadata.json")
                .build();
            metadataMap.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, metadataContentDisposition.toString());
            metadataMap.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            HttpEntity<byte[]> metadataEntity = new HttpEntity<>(((ByteArrayResource) testFileMetadataContent).getByteArray(), metadataMap);
            body.add("metadata", metadataEntity);

            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestEntity, String.class);
            log.debug("result: {}", response.getBody());
            return HttpStatus.OK.equals(response.getStatusCode());
        }
```

or via OkHttp:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
  .build();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
  .addFormDataPart("file","metadata.json",
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),
    new File("Downloads/tempmetadata.json")))
  .addFormDataPart("metadata","metadata.json",
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),
    new File("Downloads/tempmetadata.json")))
  .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url(MYURL)
  .method("POST", body)
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```